# Plot postcodes on London Map in R

Tags: r, maps

I have a column of over 1,000 London full postcodes. I need to convert these postcodes into Latitudes and Longitudes and then plot each point onto a base map of London. I want to show the spatial distribution and concentration of my postcodes as dots on London.

I have attempted this exercise using ggmap, maps and mapdata but to no avail.

```
install.packages("ggmap")

install.packages(c("maps", "mapdata"))

library(ggmap)
library(mapdata)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
mapdata <- filter(mapdata, Country--'UK')
```

Error Message:

> Error in as.ts(x) : object 'mapdata' not found

Comment: Where do you expect `mapdata`to come from? The package `mapdata`doesn't contain a dataset with that name.

Answer (score 0):

First, I found a shapefile layer of UK water [here](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/). You might wish to find a better one. It's best to download all your shapefiles in ONE GIS FOLDER for future use, including all the files that are zipped along with them.

Second, I used the `rgdal` package to open that shapefile using the `readOGR` command.

Third, I used the `leaflet` package to place that data on a map of London.

```
library(leaflet);library(rgdal)
setwd("/yourpathhere/")  #update your path here

ukwater<-readOGR(dsn='.',layer='GBR_water_lines_dcw')

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner") %>% 
  setView(0,51.4,zoom=9) %>%  # longitude and latitute, respectively
  addPolygons(data=ukwater)
```

Comment: Why would you want to download all your shapefiles in one folder? That's not necessarily good advice.

Comment: I keep subdirectories, of course, for shapefiles of different subjects/topics.  I meant that all of my shapefile data, writ large, are stored in one folder. For me, at least, it's much easier to manage my data this way.